# Which BUS supports shared IRQs and BUS mastering?

Tags: bus

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the selective choices here.

1. PCI
2. ISA
3. VGA
4. USB

I'm going out on a limb here but I don't want it to break. PCI? No? What would it be, then?

Comment: VGA is not even a bus.  USB is a master-slaves bus.  PCI, EISA, Microchannel and ISA are capable of bus mastering, although IIRC there were very few ISA cards that did (e.g. a few SCSI host bus adapters).

Comment: So I think I'd go with PCI, no? Thanks for the tips, too.

Comment: Would you like us to write your test for you too?

Comment: Sure. Anyone is welcome to help and write a future exam. And thanks, yeah I figured. PCI would be my best bet anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love Yellow Submarine and sing when riding the bus. You can insert PCI, ISA, VGA and USB into the lyrics and most people will just smile and nod.

Note to the OP - since you are dealing with a multiple guess question you should start by eliminating the answers that could not be correct. For example, two of the four do not have an IRQ channel. Both of the remaining choices have multiple IRQ lines with one of them dedicating one line per device and the other having a protocol defined in the bus spec for how to share them.